# Turning on Smooth Pixel Transformation in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wms

How do I turn on "Smooth Pixel Transformation" in QGIS?

Comment: What have you researched/tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the WMS connection properties is a checkbox "Smooth pixmap transform". Check this option in the connection properties before you add the WMS layer to QGIS.